# C# Javascript codes only work on a single Tabcontrol tab

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I made a tabbed browser using Cefsharp and Tabcontrol, but the java processes only work on the first tab.

**This is how I activated Cefsharp.**

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(txtURL1.Text);
        chrome.Parent = tabControl.SelectedTab;
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
        chrome.TitleChanged += Chrome_TitleChanged;
        chrome.LoadingStateChanged += Chrome_LoadingStateChanged;
        FormSizer();
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

**This is how I opened the new tab via tabcontrol**

```
 private void btnNewTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        tab.Text = txtName2.Text + "- NewTab";
        tabControl.Controls.Add(tab);
        tabControl.SelectTab(tabControl.TabCount - 1);
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(txtURL2.Text);
        chrome.Parent = tab;
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chrome.TitleChanged += Chrome_TitleChanged;
    }
```

**This is how I ran the java codes after the page was loaded.(TLoader)**

```
 private void Chrome_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            bool CheckLoad = e.IsLoading;
            if (CheckLoad == false)
                if (OpenSetValue <= 2)
                {
                    TLoader();
                    OpenSetValue++;
                }
            
        }));
    }
```

**Java content is exactly like this**

```
 private void TLoader()
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
        
        if (chrome != null)
        {
        string ClickName = "document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value ='" + SelectName + "'";
        string ClickPass = "document.querySelector('input[type=password]').value ='" + SelectPass + "'";
        string ClickButton = "document.querySelector('button[type=submit]').click();";
        //    MessageBox.Show(ClickPass);
        Thread.Sleep(348);
        chrome.ExecuteScriptAsync(ClickName); //id
        chrome.ExecuteScriptAsync(ClickPass); //pass
        Thread.Sleep(541);
        chrome.ExecuteScriptAsync(ClickButton); //click
            
        }
    }
```

Opening a new tab via tabcontrol and loading the cefsharp browser works fine, but "TLoader" does not work except in the first tab. **It doesn't work on other tabs.**

**What do I need to do so that I can run TLoader on the selected or visible tab?**

*Thanks.*

Comment: That's not Java...

Comment: Looks like you are using `WinForms`, I'd suggest adding a `winforms` tag. `Chrome_LoadingStateChanged` is not tied to the active tab, if you want to get the `ChromiumWebBrowser` associated with the event then cast `sender` to `ChromiumWebBrowser`.